# Capped wires in old switch box--mains power or switch loop?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have an old switch box that has a single cable coming into it with a black wire and a white wire. I've confirmed with a voltage tester that the black wire is hot. Before installing an electronic remote switch, I want to make sure that the white wire is a neutral.

My doubt comes because my house has a number of switches that are set up as a switch loop, where a single cable comes into the box, and one of the conductors is always hot (usually fed by power coming into the fixture) and the other conductor is used as a switched hot. In this old switch box, I'm wondering whether the cable is an abandoned switch loop where the always hot conductor is still connected but the switched hot doesn't connect to a load.

Is there a way to test this?  I believe that measuring hot to neutral on a multimeter should give 120V, correct?  What would measuring hot to switched hot give?  I'm just looking for a way to safely and definitively confirm that the non-hot wire is a neutral on the same circuit as the hot wire.

Comment: Is this a NM cable or a BX (armored) cable? Can you post a photo of the inside of the box? Can you find where that cable leads?

Comment: BX. I'll post a pic when I get home. Unfortunately it won't really be possible to definitively determine where the cable leads because all the walls are finished.

Comment: Measure the voltage from the white wire to the box then, it should be near 0 volts if it's a neutral.

Comment: Will try that but wouldn't voltage to ground also be zero if it's an unconnected switched hot leg?  I'm concerned there was a fixture or receptacle back in the day that's no longer there from which they branched a switch loop, and when the switch was no longer needed, they left the hot connected but abandoned the switched hot conductor. In the box, both wires are capped individually and there's no other cables in or out.

Comment: No, an unconnected switched hot leg will read a floating voltage on a high-impedance meter (like your average digital meter) due to capacitive coupling to the live hot wire

Comment: Thanks. Excuse the basic layman's question, but what does a floating voltage mean? How will that show up on the multimeter?  I'll measure tonight and report back.

Comment: It'll show up as an indeterminate reading, perhaps several volts, perhaps close to 120V.

Comment: Here's another plan/idea: get a 1.79 lamp cord style 6' extension cord and chop the male plug off. Strip the wires on the female end and wire nut them to the hot and questioned neutral.  Now you have a safe way to plug a lamp in.  I'd use a plain old 100w incandescent light bulb.  As an added bonus since those lamp ext cords usually have 3 plugs you can now safely test the voltage under load (I.e. With the lightbulb turned on)

Comment: Is the hot wire connected to a known breaker? Turn the breaker to off,  connect a receptacle to the pair and plug in circuit tester and turn the breaker on.

Comment: In your cases of a single cable being used as a "switch loop" was the white wire marked with black tape to show it was converted to a hot?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, check for continuity between White and Ground.

If you have 120V between White and Black, and White is tied to Ground (check for close to 0 ohms resistance from white to ground), then White is neutral, Black is Hot.

There are some miswired options that may be in play (ie switched neutral), but hopefully this was wired by someone who knows what they are doing.

To answer your other questions:
I believe that measuring hot to neutral on a multimeter should give 120V, correct? 
Correct

What would measuring hot to switched hot give?
120V, assuming that there is a functional light bulb or functioning device plugged into the switched socket.  If not, then you would read 0v, or some floating voltage much less than 120V.